# Find $F_Z(\max(z,0))$ given $Z\sim N(0,1)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm breaking a very large question into smaller and smaller parts and I finally can understand something, but still some parts are missing. Bigger Question is found on statistics site along with the description http://www.talkstats.com/threads/calculating-cauchys-pdf-using-domain-definition-drawings-of-f_x-y-z.74806/

My current question is:

> Given $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Find $F_Z(\max(z,0))$.

How to work with these min/max formulas when they appear in the CDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this as a piecewise formula. Since $\max(z,0)= \begin{cases} z & z \geq 0 \\ 0 & z<0 \end{cases}$,
$$F_Z(\max(z,0)) = \begin{cases}F_Z(z) & z \geq 0 \\ F_Z(0) & z<0 \end{cases} = \begin{cases} F_Z(z) & z \geq 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & z<0\end{cases}.$$

---

I took a look at your linked question, and I'm not sure why you're trying to find $F_Z(\max(z,0))$. In addition, you've written $F_Z(z)=P(z \leq Z)$, but it should be $F_Z(z)=P(Z \leq z)$.

So you ought to have:
$$F_Z(z)=P(Z \leq z) = P\left(\frac{X}{Y}\leq z\right).$$

Note that by symmetry, if $z=0$ we have $P(Z \leq z)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Now if $z>0$, then $\frac{X}{Y} \leq z$ whenever $X$ and $Y$ have opposite signs, and also when $X,Y>0$ and $Y \geq \frac{Z}{x}$, and when $X,Y <0$ and $Y \leq \frac{X}{z}$. The shaded region below shows the region we are trying to find the probability of. This can be found using double integrals in polar coordinates.
[image]

If $z<0$, then $\frac{X}{Y} \leq z$ can only happen when $X$ and $Y$ have opposite signs. If $X>0, Y<0$, the inequality becomes $Y \geq \frac{X}{z}$, while if $X<0,Y>0$ it becomes $Y \leq \frac{X}{z}$. The region for this case is shown below:

[image]

This can also be found using a double integral in polar coordinates.

Alternatively, you can note that by symmetry $\frac{X}{Y}$ must be symmetrically distributed about $0$, and so you need only find one half of the CDF.

Comment: Which is in turn ${\frac 1 2}u(-z)+u(z)F_Z(z)$ in one-liner, is that correct? EDIT: I will mark as the answer since it is my responsibility to find the one-liner. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what $u(\cdot)$ means. See my edits which more directly address your main question.

Comment: Oh sorry I think I do need to make some changes...

Comment: Yeah I understood I confused you (even personally) with my bigger question, but I have to show up my work here according to site politics which refers I guess basic polite rules :) . So besides trying to be polite the $P(Z>max(z,0))$ is due to the Law of Total Probability which I used there. After developing it shows up. Regarding $u()$, it's a step function. We learn it in Engineering school, perhaps in other facultes it's called otherwise.

Comment: No changes needed!!! :) :) :) I recognize this pattern in your answer, I've seen it my homework. It's just we had like 1000 exercises already and I get lost at that level of solving HW. Your answer is good. You can edit if for your own benifit, but you were clear enough and answered my question. Many thanks! I'll keep up from here.

Comment: No, there were mistakes in my answer - you cannot rearrange the inequality without considering the signs of $Y$ and $z$. I have fixed it now. For future note, it would be more helpful to show your work by showing how you got to trying to compute $F_Z(\max(z,0))$. Simply asking how to compute $F_Z(\max(z,0))$ doesn't actually demonstrate any effort toward a solution.

Comment: Regarding the "off topic" I'm back to work on it again and will expand on it tomorrow since I'm getting something wierd. I'm afraid you have mistakes in marking the grey areas. You can see you've got CDF of 1 there. An example: when you say $Y > \frac X z$, the area shall be above $\frac X z$ and not below.

Comment: I have double-checked my inequalities and the shaded regions. I don't see any mistake. Where do you think I've written $Y>\frac{X}{z}$ but shaded below the line?

Comment: On the down most at the left side. $Y>0$, $X<0$ $z<0$. For $Y$ to be greater than $\frac X z$ line it needs to be on the top, above the line and not below it. $A)$ $Y=1000,$ $X=-50,$ $Z=-2$ $B)$ $50/2=25$ $C)$ $1000>25$ $=>$ the relevant area is above $Y= \frac X z$. Just check it it shall be all the Y values that make this happen. X/z is one line and it has an area of Y values. Those value shall be greater than the line since both X and z are <0.

Comment: In that case the inequality $\frac{X}{Y} \leq z$ becomes $X \leq Y\cdot z$ which becomes $\frac{X}{z} \geq Y$ (note that $z<0$ so we have to flip the sign of the inequality when we divide by $z$). So $Y \leq \frac{X}{z}$ and the shading should be below the line as I have drawn.

Comment: ${\frac {-5} {1000}} {\nless} -2$ And you are right. Many thanks (again!) I will check my wrong solution in the notebook, perhaps this is the root of all evil.

Comment: Found my mistake. I looked only at the the X,Y graph's areas where X/z passes through! Actually thanks to you I understand now. Indeed there are areas with no X/z inside we shall take into account when using the Total Probability Theorem as I did here. Many thanks!

Comment: I looked over your solution on areas deviation and compared it to my solution. I devided by writing the formula of $X/z$ and comparing it to Y "in general" while trying to conclude on which areas are we taking the integrals. Now this is a very much of error prone, since we swipe sign many times. You kept within the idiom of $X/Y \less z$ and generalized it successfully - even for where $X/z$ does not go through. You understood the problematic way of sign swipes and proposed a much safer solution through a safer way. I think you deserve at least to be notified on that :).

Comment: I apologies so much for spam. Your way was indeed great and I had to mention that. But the double integral diverges. When $X$ runs from 0 to infinity, we get infinite area between y=0 and $X/-|z|$. I run in the very same problem again. We need to somehow encapsulate X and Y ranges I guess and I don't know how.

Comment: I'm sorry again for spam. I understood it all eventually: I was refering to the integral which is the area itself, whereas I had to calculate the integral of *the probability* inside this area. Which is of course converges. Many thanks! I learnt something.